# false or true != true or false != true || false

Tags: ruby

This took me quite some time today, and I finaly found the cause, but still don't get the logic

```
x = (complex expression evaluating to false) or (complex expression evaluating to true)

x => false
```

Very strange... It turns out, after experimenting that

```
false or true => false
true or false => true
false || true => true
true || false => true
```

I guess I've used the "or" operator in hundreds of places in my code, and honestly speaking, I don't trust the "or" anymore...

Can someone please explain the "logic"?

Comment: Your second block is not strictly correct. You actually have something like `x = false or true; p x # => false`, right? It's when the assignment happens that is confusing you. In short, assignment is just another operator, it is processed *before* `or` and *after* `||`. Usually you want `||`, but the semantics of `or` are still useful from time-to-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [precedence](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) table `or` has lower precedence than `=`. Thus `x = true or false` will be evaluated as `(x = true) or false`. But `||` has higher precedence than `=`, `x = true || false` will be evaluated as `x = (true || false)`.

```
x = false or true
x # => false
x = false || true
x # => true
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all the expressions `false or true`, `true or false`, `false || true` and `true || false` are all `true`. If you type them into irb, you will see that.

The reason that your code doesn't work like you expect is the precedence of `or` versus `=`. `x = y or z` is parsed as `(x = y) or z`, not `x = (y or z)`. With `||` it's parsed as `x = (y || z)` because `||` has higher precedence.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ((complex expression evaluating to false) or (complex expression evaluating to true))
# or
x = (complex expression evaluating to false) || (complex expression evaluating to true)
```

in this expression

```
x = (complex expression evaluating to false) or (complex expression evaluating to true)
```

here is actually two of them. First is assignment

```
x = (complex expression evaluating to false)
```

and if assignment will return `false` second expression will be evaluated. But `x` will be `false` even if second expression is true.

This is happenning because of `or` has less priority then `=`